# Simple AngularJS scope issue (newbie)

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to figure out how to get my user's email passed to my controller but I'm getting `undefined` for `$scope.user.email`. `$scope` is defined but there's no `user` object in there. Is there something wrong with my code?

**html**

```
<label class="item item-input">
  <span class="input-label">Email</span>
  <input ng-model="user.email" type="text">
</label>
<button ng-click="signInClick()" class="button button-full button-positive">
    Sign In
</button>
```

**controller**

```
.controller('WelcomeCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.signInClick = function() {
        console.log($scope.user.email);
    }
})
```

## EDITS

The controller is linked via the `js/apps.js` and runs when my button is clicked so I know it's linked to `WelcomeCtrl`.

Comment: Is the input field within the right part of the html that is controllled by WelcomeCtrl? Could you make a jsfiddle or plunker with an example?

Comment: From the code that you're showing us you're not defining the `user` object anywhere

Comment: @inorganik what do you mean "defining the `user` object"? Steve I added an edit for your question, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Exactly what I said, you never declare $scope.user anywhere, see @LanceVo's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because $scope.user is undefined.

```
.controller('WelcomeCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.user = {};
    $scope.signInClick = function() {
        console.log($scope.user.email);
    }
})
```

Comment: Now `user` is an object but email is showing up as `undefined`.

Comment: Wow. I'm not even going to tell you why the email input value was coming across as undefined. I've been working on this project for way too long. Thanks Lance.